# React-dnd state not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, state

I´am trying to make a copy of board game called Cartographers using react, dnd-react. When a component renders it gets random type of terrain and based on type of terrain it has different colour. My problem is that when I drop Slice somewhere on the board it fires end function, which uses randomTerrain(). New slice get random terrain type again and new color. But when i try to console.log(slice) it´s always printing first terrain that was setup by useState, which is problem , because I need to pass it to Board component, which also always gets only first terrain type as console.log(slice). It apparently changes to correct state but it takes like 10 minutes.
Thank you in advance for help :)

```
import { Text, Center } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDrag } from 'react-dnd'
import { ItemTypes } from '../utils/Constants'

export default function Slice() {

    const possibleTerrain = ["water", "field", "forrest", "village"]
    const [slice, setSlice] = useState(possibleTerrain[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleTerrain.length)])


    const randomTerrain = () => {
        const index = (Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleTerrain.length));
        setSlice(possibleTerrain[index]);
        console.log(slice)
    }


    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
        type: ItemTypes.SLICE,
        item: { slice },
        collect: monitor => ({
            item: monitor.getItem(),
            isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
        }),
        end: (props, monitor) => {
            if (monitor.didDrop()) {
                randomTerrain();
            }
        },
    }))

    const componentStyle = {
        water: { backgroundColor: "blue" },
        field: { backgroundColor: "yellow" },
        forrest: { backgroundColor: "green" },
        village: { backgroundColor: "red" },
    }[slice];

    return (
        <Center ref={drag} w="5.9vw" h="7.72vh" style={componentStyle} >
            <Text>{slice}</Text>
        </Center>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe adding dependency array to useDrag() hook shoulde do the trick.

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: ItemTypes.SLICE,
    item: { slice },
    collect: monitor => ({
        item: monitor.getItem(),
        isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
    end: (props, monitor) => {
        if (monitor.didDrop()) {
            randomTerrain();
        }
    },
}), [slice])
```